# Calculate the intercept from lm

Tags: r, lm, intercept

I would like to understand how I can compute by hand the intercept from lm. 
The following example is a fractional factorial design (3^3) and the variables are factors.

```
f1 <- factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3))
f2 <- factor(c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3))
f3 <- factor(c(3,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,1))
r <- c(77.311, 70.838, 87.173, 60.831, 74.898, 70.743,
73.946, 64.263, 64.624)

d <- data.frame(f1, f2, f3, r)

mod1 <- lm(r~., data = d)
summary(mod1)
```

I would like to understand how the intercept 71.3172 is calculated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the coefficient estimators in the model (included the intercept estimator) are computed using the standard [ordinary least squares (OLS) estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) used in linear regression.  Before replicating the calculation manually, we can produce the coefficients from the `lm` function.

```
#Input the data and model
DATA  <- data.frame(f1, f2, f3, r);
MODEL <- lm(r ~ ., data = DATA);

#Extract the coefficient estimates
summary(MODEL)$coefficients

               Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  71.3172222   1.197402 59.5599462 0.0002817785
f12          -9.6166667   1.108579 -8.6747673 0.0130296029
f13         -10.8296667   1.108579 -9.7689607 0.0103167234
f22          -0.6963333   1.108579 -0.6281313 0.5940817326
f23           3.4840000   1.108579  3.1427615 0.0880753355
f32          13.2413333   1.108579 11.9444179 0.0069363819
f33           5.3413333   1.108579  4.8181793 0.0404784180
```

We can replicate these estimated coefficients manually using the OLS formula.  Letting $\mathbf{x}$ be the design matrix and $\mathbf{r}$ the response vector, the estimated coefficient vector is $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} = (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{r})$.  This can be programmed in `R` using matrix operations.  We see that this replicates the same numbers calculated in the `lm` function.

```
#Compute the coefficient estimator manually
DESIGN <- model.matrix(r ~ ., data = DATA);
COEF   <- solve(t(DESIGN) %*% DESIGN, t(DESIGN) %*% r);
colnames(COEF) <- "Estimate";

#Extract the coefficient estimates
COEF;

               Estimate
(Intercept)  71.3172222
f12          -9.6166667
f13         -10.8296667
f22          -0.6963333
f23           3.4840000
f32          13.2413333
f33           5.3413333
```

Answer (score 2):

The intercept is the baseline value excluding explanatory variables. Because your explanatory variables are all categorical, in practice your regression will simply calculate means per group. In fact, your data supposes 3 times 3 = 27 unique groups. R will generally choose one group as the baseline and then give the added value of the other groups. In your case, the output is:

```
(Intercept)   71.317      1.197   59.56  0.00028 ***
f12           -9.617      1.109   -8.67  0.01303 *  
f13          -10.830      1.109   -9.77  0.01032 *  
f22           -0.696      1.109   -0.63  0.59408    
f23            3.484      1.109    3.14  0.08808 .  
f32           13.241      1.109   11.94  0.00694 ** 
f33            5.341      1.109    4.82  0.04048 *
```

The intercept in this case is the value of the group (1,1,1) - which is not actually in your data, but this is the expected value of this group if it were. The coefficients should be read as follows: for coefficient fxy, x indicates for which variable the coefficient is given and y indicates what value the variable gets (1, 2 or 3 in your case). Since the baseline group is (1,1,1), a value for y of 1 never occurs, it is already the base value.

Small example: f12 shows the expected value of changing the first variable to group 2, meaning a group characterised by (2,1,1), which is in your data (value = 60.8, estimate from model is 71.3-9.6 = 61.7). To calculate the expectation of group (2,2,1), add both the f12 coefficient and the f22 coefficient (71.3 - 9.6 - 0.7 = 61). Finally, the expected value for group (2,2,2), which is in your data with value 74.9, would be Intercept + f12 + f22 + f32 = 71.3-9.6-0.7+13.2 = 74.2

Thus, to summarise, the intercept is that group or those observations where all regressors have a value of zero, in your case meaning the remaining group.

EDIT: to calculate the expected value of (3,3,3), you add f13, f23 and f33 to the intercept. I just realised my examples above may not cover that you do **not** add both f12 and f13 to the intercept to get the first factor variable to 3.